# How to run this Github python project on local machine?

Tags: python, github

Recently found this python project on Github:https://github.com/dAPTaset/dAPTaset

Wanted to run it on local machine and play around with it but not sure what framework or platform it would run on. No notes found on the initial setup and wanted to be able to run this. Any hints or pointers on what platform/framework/solution to use would help.

Comment: There is a `requirements.txt` file in the `code/` folder. Search for "python requirements.txt".

Comment: i would just download it all (clone repository) and run it in `vs code`...

Comment: main.py is not running on Vs code and requirements just showcase some of the frameworks in needs a pacakages..... not running :(